# How are codons read in Grammatical Evolution: are they a sliding window or are they done in chunks?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I'm reading the paper by O'Neill and Ryan and they say this:

> each codon represents an integer value where codons are consecutive
>   groups of 8 bits

So I just want to make sure, two successive codons would be bits `1-8`, then `9-16` right? Or would they be bits `1-8`, `2-9`, `3-10` etc?

Comment: Please, next time you have a question about evolutionary algorithms, ask it on [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have read "Grammatical Swarm: The generation of programs by social programming" (M. O’Neill, A. Brabazon, 2006). In this paper the authors are quite clear about the genome being represented as an **array of integer numbers** (8-bit, unsigned) representing codons. A codon with value `c` is mapped to an expansion rule of a symbol as `Rule = c % r`, where `r` is the number of choices for the symbol.

They also describe a genome wrapping operator to make a GE genome easier fit particle swarm optimization method, but this does not seem to be relevant to the original question and does not change to genome representation.